# How to set GRAPHVIZ_GRAPH_HEADER in Cmake?

Tags: python, cmake, graphviz

I am working upon a Cmake in which I want to use

```
GRAPHVIZ_GRAPH_HEADER - default: 'node [\n fontsize = \"20\"\n];'
```

Currently I am setting it in Cmake as :

```
set( GRAPHVIZ_GRAPH_HEADER default: 'node [\n fontsize = \"20\"\n];' )
```

But in output I am not getting text font as 20.
So, kindly help out how can I set font of graph text using GRAPHVIZ_GRAPH_HEADER option?

Answer (score 0):

In [CMakeGraphVizOptions](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/CMakeGraphVizOptions.html#variable:GRAPHVIZ_GRAPH_HEADER) says the default value for `GRAPHVIZ_GRAPH_HEADER` is `“node [n fontsize = “12”];”`
I'd try

```
set( GRAPHVIZ_GRAPH_HEADER default: 'node [\n n fontsize = \"20\"\n];' )
```

And I'd also try unescaping the double quotes, if adding `n` doesn't work

Comment: I used set( GRAPHVIZ_GRAPH_HEADER default: 'node [\n n fontsize = \"20\"\n];' ) but again it doesnt changes the font size.

Comment: Is that header appearing in the output file, or is it writing the default 12 font size?

Comment: Hey, its working now but output is not clear its coming as: default:'node;[; rotate;=;90;]. How do i get it as node[ rotate = 90 ]?